# How to enable tty and run interactive console with AWS ECS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

Deployed a Dockerized Rails Application on EC2 instance with AWS ECS service. I am using `ecs-cli` for deploying rails application which using `docker-compose.yml` file for deploying containers as services similar to `docker-compose` mode. For running interactive shell such as `rails console` for my app, I created one separate service with following definition:

```
version: '2'

volumes: 
  app-tmp:
    driver: local
  app-logs:
    driver: local

services:
  console:
    image: acc-name.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/docker_image_name:latest
    command: bundle exec rails c
    hostname: console
    mem_limit: 314572800
    env_file: ../.prod-env
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    ports: []
    volumes:
      - "app-logs:/home/app/log"
      - "app-tmp:/home/app/tmp"
```

But when I deploy the task with following command:

```
ecs-cli compose -f docker/docker-compose-console.yml --project-name app-console run console "bundle exec rails c"
```

The flags `tty: true` and `stdin_open: true` are ignored. Due to which the task running console boots up, changes to `RUNNING` state and then silently closes down with state 0.

Is there any way one can run interactive console session or tailed logs? What approaches are used to achieve similar behavior?

**TL;DR**: I want behavior similar to `docker-compose run app rails c` with AWS ECS service.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In task configuration click `Configure via JSON` button.
Change `pseudoTerminal` property to `true`.
`"pseudoTerminal": true`

Comment: And then how do you actually connect to the instance?

Comment: Sadly, you can't actually connect to the allocated pseudoTerminal. Without these options, if your container needed to allocate a terminal session, it wouldn't be able to and would stop immediately. With these options enabled, the container will continue to run whatever process is specified, but you can't connect to it. The docs aren't very clear on this at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to start an ECS task and be connected to the allocated TTY session created by the startup command. There seems to be two options to do this...

1. Start an ECS task as normal with pretty much any command that will keep the container running. Then find the instance that the task was allocated to and SSH into that host and use `docker exec` to start your console. This downside with this method is that the container won't exit when you end your session. You'd have to manually end the task when you are done.
2. Run the container somewhere else. You could run the container locally if your local network has access to all the resources needed for the container. Otherwise you could use an EC2 instance to run your container inside your VPC.

Answer (score 0):

It is now.  Just follow the instructions posted [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/new-using-amazon-ecs-exec-access-your-containers-fargate-ec2/)

Comment: Please add the linked content in your answer here, it might move to another location.